# How to reenable autostart of compiz?

Tags: 11.10, compiz, configuration, autostart

After upgrading to 11.10 compiz won't start automatically and I have to run `compiz --replace` after each reboot. How to start it automatically instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running unity 2d, the default, try Dash -> Startup Applications -> Add. Now:

```
Name:Compiz
Command: bash -c "sleep 2; compiz --replace"
```

Sleep 2 lets the system wait for 2 seconds before loading compiz, of course it is optional (you can use bash -c "compiz --replace" instead) but it is useful, because it allows the system to be ready to composite the screen correctly. For example it is necessary if you use screenlets, they must be loaded before calling compiz --replace to show correctly.

Comment: I just added `compiz --replace` to Startup Applications in Unity 3D (normal Ubuntu session).

Comment: `compiz --replace` did not work on my machine (older laptop), looked for a solution why (it worked previously on a higher-end desktop computer) and found this. `bash -c "sleep 2; compiz --replace"` did the trick, thanks. Maybe this is due to the weaker processor and HDD instead of SSD.