# How to enable desktop effects on my Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, compiz

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 yesterday, and have been struggling with enabling desktop effects for hours. I downloaded the CompizConfig Settings Manager, and tried selecting-deselcting various items. But they don't seem to be taking effect. Please help. Thanks.

VGA: `00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82946GZ/GL Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)`

EDIT:

New problem! I made a few changes in CompizConfig settings, and a few effects started working. Like wobbly windows, and rotating cube.

Then I tried enabling a few application switchers, and it asked me to resolve the conflicts. I guess one of them was "enable OpenGL".

As I clicked it, everything crashed. Dock vanished. I only a see one bar at top with menus File, Edit, .., Bookmarks, Help.

I am not able to access anything else. [Alt] + [F2] and [Super], both are not working. What do I do? Please help! (Right now I am accessing web via a guest account. To get any work done, I *have to* be able to use my own account again.)

Comment: What video card do you have ? lspci | grep VGA

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82946GZ/GL Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: I should perhaps mention that I was a Linux Mint user for over 2 years and all desktop effects worked flawlessly. Never had issues.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: Please see the updated question.

Comment: delete your compiz configuration file: `cd && rm -rf .config/config-1` . That will get you back into unity. Also please post the output of `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p`

Comment: @severin: I think you meant `compiz1`. Yes, I tried that too. (via GUI) Didn't help. Couldn't try out that `support_test` command because, well, I have no way to access the terminal.

Comment: yes, I meant `.config/compiz-1`. Please, try again, using the commandline. As you are able to access your system with a guest account, it definitely means your settings are messed up and they are stored there.

Comment: @severin: Marc Simpson (korsch on twitter) helped me out. https://twitter.com/#!/korsch/status/143381598325309441.

Comment: @UriHerrera: Good suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reset my Compiz settings using the commands provided in [this blog post](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/how-to-reset-unity-launcher-icons-or.html), and it worked.In particular, the following command did the trick:

```
gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/compiz-1
unity --reset
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you should look into the additional drivers that might be required to enable desktop effects. **System->Administration->Additional Drivers**.

Alos look at this documentation page [Restricted Drivers](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedDrivers)

Comment: "No proprietary drivers are in use on this system."

Comment: Intel GPUs don't need that option

Comment: may be you can refer this link [http://askubuntu.com/questions/83379/how-to-reenable-autostart-of-compiz](link)

Comment: @techubuntu: Please see the updated question.

Comment: @Uri: Please see the updated question.